# c++ int array with values of 2 dimension int array (3d array)

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to make an array which contain int[][] items

i.e

```
int version0Indexes[][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8} };
int version1Indexes[][4] = { ...... };

int version15Indexes[][4] = { ... };
```

(total of 16)

```
int indexes[][][] = { version0Indexes,version1Indexes, .. };
```

anyone can suggest how to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know how big an array will be at runtime, you have to allocate the array on the heap.

Comment: Do you want contiguous memory or array of pointers ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array of pointers to array:

```
int (*indexes[])[4] = { version0Indexes, version1Indexes, .. };
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you inline your arrays inside `indexes`:

```
int indexes[][2][4] = {
    { { 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8} },
    { {....}, {....} }
    ....
}
```

Or you make `indexes` an array of pointers:

```
int (*indexes[])[4] = { version0Indexes, version1Indexes, .... };
```

What you wrote in your question is not directly possible because, when used, an array variable is actually a pointer (that's why `indices` has to be an array of pointers).

Comment: `int indexes[][][4]` is an array of incomplete type and will not compile.